# Debugging a continuas value Android Studio

Tags: java, debugging, android-studio

At the moment I've been using logging to keep a track of my continuously changing values within an update loop. Problem is is that this can be time consuming.

I can use the debugger but it stops code executing and due to what I'm doing causes weird results and false values.

Does anyone know if it's possible to "watch" the variables while keeping the code running. Like having one watch within a scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio/IntelliJ have some really nice features in breakpoints that let the IDE take an action when it hits a breakpoint instead of just dropping your app into the debugger (which it can of course also do). On any given breakpoint, there's a checkbox in the options that controls whether it will actually suspend your app and drop it into the debugger; you can turn that on or off independently. You can have it log a message to the debugger console, or have it evaluate any expression and log the results to the console.

I find these options super-handy; it's the equivalent of adding debug logging to your code, but you can add and change it on the fly without modifying your code and doing a rebuild-restart cycle.

There's also some really powerful filtering that will selectively control whether or not the breakpoint is triggered based on certain criteria; you can even set up cascades of breakpoints where one doesn't fire until a previous one is hit.

Experiment with some of the options.

[image: Breakpoints settings window]